# Does copying ritual spells into a ritual book destroy spell scrolls?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, feats

How exactly does copying a spell into a ritual spell book work with regards to the ritual casting feat? Does it use the spell scroll in the process? I know copying a scroll destroys it if you copy it into a wizard spell book — does that apply here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, spell scrolls are always destroyed by copying. From the DMG entry on spell scrolls, page 200:

> When   a   spell   is  copied  from    a   spell scroll,   the copier  must    succeed on   an Intelligence    (Arcana)    check   with    a   DC  equal   to 10   +   the spell’s level.  If  the check   succeeds,   the spell is    successfully    copied. **Whether   the check succeeds  or fails,   the spell   scroll is   destroyed.**

(Emphasis mine.)